# Transpose CSV data using nodejs

Tags: node.js, transpose

"A",1,2,3,4

"B",1,2,3,4

"C",1,2,3,4

I want to transpose and get the output as

"A""B""C"

111

222

333

444

Comment: Hi Sai kiran bandari,

How is your source data?  Do you have a 2 dimensional array OR do you have data from a file? Please provide mor infos about your use-case

Comment: Depending on the size of the data you want to transpose, nodejs may not be the best to do the job. Nodejs is good to work with async I/O calls, because it is single-thread. If you are going to process something in memory, try with Python, that has some highly optimized matrix libs.

Answer (score 0):

Hi sai kiran bandari !

Please provide more information for your next question.

I expect you to have a 2 dimension array for which i made a solution. You want to iteratoe through the array using 2 loops and split the values to a new 2 dimension array according to first array index `i` in this case.

```js
const data =[['A', 1,2,3,4], ['B', 1,2,3,4], ['C', 1,2,3,4]]
const transposed = []

// iterate through 2 dimension array..
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var arr = data[i]

    // Iterate through inner araray
    for(let p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {

       // create new inner array if there is not already one at destination..
        if(Array.isArray(transposed[p]) === false) {
            transposed[p] = []
        }

        // we want to take all the values of the first array and split it 
        // up to a single array each. In the second iteration, alle the 
        // values will be splitted again and you have your transpose.
        transposed[p].push(arr[p])
    }
}

console.log(transposed)

/* Output => [
  [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ],
  [ 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 2, 2, 2 ],
  [ 3, 3, 3 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4 ]
]

*/
```